# PostgreSQL - Set JSONB property from column value

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a numeric column `total_price` and I want to move it to a jsonb property named `price_detail`. For example, if the `total_price` value is 1000, the expected `price_detail` value is `{"totalPrice": 1000}`

I've tried using `jsonb_set` but the result is empty object `{}`

```
UPDATE public.orders SET price_detail =
       jsonb_set('{}'
               , '{}'
               , jsonb_build_object('totalPrice', total_price::numeric))
```

If I set the path,

```
UPDATE public.orders SET price_detail =
       jsonb_set('{}'
               , '{totalPrice}'
               , jsonb_build_object('totalPrice', total_price::numeric))
```

The result is `{"totalPrice":{"totalPrice":1000}}` which is unexpected

How can I set the `totalPrice` property correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `JSONB_SET`, just use `JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT`:

```
UPDATE orders 
SET price_detail = JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('totalPrice', total_price::numeric)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d370362970a54209493e02159bd19703)